# TLS client and server on Windows [openssl vs. sspi vs. cryptlib]

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, x509certificate

Let me say that I am doing this first time and I know very little in this domain (learning more).

My requirement is to implement a secure channel of communication between server and client.
I will be proved x509 certificate on both side (server/client). Communication will via sockets.

One option is to use openssl. But priority is to develop it on the Windows API.

I see two options cryptolib & sspi.

Please suggest what is best and proven option on Windows.

Comment: I think Gutmann's Cryptlib is better written and has better documentation than OpenSSL (or maybe "more disciplined code" and "better engineering process" are better choices  of words). I also think Gutmann responds quicker to bugs. But OpenSSL is more popular and has more copy/paste tutorials. There's other SSl/TLS libraries, if needed. See [Related Links](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Related_Links) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL works just fine on Windows, and there are precompiled DLLs available if you do not want to compile it yourself.

But, if for whatever reason, you cannot use OpenSSL, then have a look at SChannel:

[Secure Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx)

[Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374782.aspx)

It uses SSL/TLS and CryptoAPI internally.  It also allows you to do your own socket I/O, so you can add it to existing socket code.

Alternatively, have a look at WinSock's built-in security:

[Winsock Secure Socket Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394815.aspx)